# How to find if a date is from a Odd or Even week?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In my table I have for each day:

```
Id_______Startdate _______ EndDate __________MondayMorning _____MondayEvening ___TuMorning  ....  
121 _____2012-01-01________2012-12-31 ________2 ___________________2______________2   
122 _____2012-02-01________2012-08-05 ________1 ___________________2______________3
```

I already generated a list of dates using the Startdate and EndDate.

I want to know if this dates belongs to a odd week or a even week so that I can filter days from my output that have number 3 Or 1 (see second record).

how can I filter the days that belongs to  odd weeks and even weeks that have number 1 and 3?

Comment: Is Monday or Sunday the start of the week? Does the first week start on January 1st and potentially have less than 7 days?

Comment: I have set datefirst = 1 which means monday is start of the week. No weeks are not always starting on 1 January. I can have 53 weeks.

Comment: @user1781398 - Please ***define*** your rules for determing which week number a particular date belongs to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `datepart` with the `wk` argument to determine the week number:

```
 SELECT datepart(wk, YourDate)
```

From there, you can use modulus to determine if the week number is even or odd:

```
 SELECT datepart(wk, YourDate) % 2
```

This will return 0 for even numbered weeks, and 1 for odd numbered weeks.

Comment: I'd mention `SET DATEFIRST` as this setting fundamentally controls how `DATEPART(wk)` works.  Also, not all systems have Jan 1st as week1 - Some assign a week to the year that atleast 4 of it's days are in.  So, Jan1st could be week 53 of the previous year...

Comment: This is not working when I set datefirst 1. but I have my own function that returns the correct weeknumber, so the modulo is working fine.

Comment: @user1781398 - define "not working".  Are the values not what you expected?

Comment: When I axecute SELECT datepart(wk, getdate()) % 2
Then I get 1 as return value which is not correct.

Comment: @user1781398 - using `DATEFIRST 1`, '2012-11-01' is week is 45, not 44.

Comment: As others have hinted: using this approach might return 2 odd weeks in a row around Jan 1st (week 53 and week 1). This shouldn't be a definite answer. Counting weeks since an epoch sound a better approach.